# Efficient way to calculate many Dutch auctions?

Tags: sorting, data-compression, constraint-satisfaction

I have 4,500 ($N$) unique items, and I want to auction each one off to the highest bidder (break ties arbitrarily).

Each item has $T$ binary traits. Since it is too complex for the $B$ bidders to specify a bid for each individual item, instead the bidders express preferences in the form of "I am willing to pay $x$ for an item with the following traits: $t_1, ... t_k$".

My plan right now is for each bidder and for each item, compute the bidder's bid: $0$ if the item does not meet the bidder's preference and $x$ otherwise. Then iterate over all items and for each item, select the highest bidder for that item. (Each bidder can only buy a maximum of 1 item.)

The runtime for the above procedure seems to be $O(N * B)$. For $T << N << B$, what's the optimal way to auction these items?

Answer (score 0):

One reasonable way to select bids would be to formulate this as a matching problem.

Build a bipartite graph, with one left vertex per bidder and one right vertex per item.  Add an edge from a bidder to each item that meets the bidder's preference, with weight $x$ (the bidder's willingness to pay).  Then find a [maximum-weight matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching) in this bipartite graph using a standard algorithm, such as the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

This will give you the optimal way to assign items to bidders, where "optimal" means that you extract the most money from bidders.

Comment: It seems like it's still O(N * B) to construct the graph. Does it improve the runtime?

Comment: @Neel, this focuses on the highest quality solution, and will in some cases yield a better solution (i.e., make you more money) than the greedy algorithm you listed.  It doesn't improve the running time.